# wfastcgi cannot find flask app in IIS on Win7

Tags: python, iis, flask, iis-6, wfastcgi

I am trying to set up wfastcgi on IIS6 for Windows 7, but it can't find my 'app.py' file. I used http://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/ as my directions for setting it up. Below is the error message I am receiving. In my search for finding the answer, the most likely solution was that it was a permissions issue, I *believe* I gave the permissions correctly, but still no luck.

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Flask_Proj\wfastcgi.py", line 712, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Flask_Proj\wfastcgi.py", line 569, in read_wsgi_handler return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)
File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Flask_Proj\wfastcgi.py", line 552, in get_wsgi_handler raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name)
ValueError: app.app could not be imported StdOut: StdErr:
```

Here is the `Web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Flask_Proj\" />
  </appSettings>

    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <add name="FlaskHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python34\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Flask_Proj\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Also, to make your life easier, here's a snippet of the code to the `wfastcgi.py` file:

```
def get_wsgi_handler(handler_name):
    if not handler_name:
        raise Exception('WSGI_HANDLER env var must be set')

    if not isinstance(handler_name, str):
        if sys.version_info >= (3,):
            handler_name = handler_name.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
        else:
            handler_name = handler_name.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())

    module_name, _, callable_name = handler_name.rpartition('.')
    should_call = callable_name.endswith('()')
    callable_name = callable_name[:-2] if should_call else callable_name
    name_list = [(callable_name, should_call)]
    handler = None

    while module_name:
        try:
            handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
            for name, should_call in name_list:
                handler = getattr(handler, name)
                if should_call:
                    handler = handler()
            break
        except ImportError:
            module_name, _, callable_name = module_name.rpartition('.')
            should_call = callable_name.endswith('()')
            callable_name = callable_name[:-2] if should_call else callable_name
            name_list.insert(0, (callable_name, should_call))
            handler = None

    if handler is None:
        raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name)

    return handler
```

Here are some links I had found to similar issues:

```
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28937664/Installing-Flask-app-on-IIS7.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3113de0a-3385-48dc-872b-d70deac071c6/azure-flask-python-could-not-be-imported-error-500-azure-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I had been doing wrong. It was a silly mistake, but based on my searches I probably am not the only one. I installed python, but i did not pip install Flask. Once I got that running everything else was much easier to figure out.